# Android style/shade properly ListItem layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-imageview

I have an app which uses a ListFragment. I want to style my own ListItem layout but don't know how to get desired effect. I want to it to look something like this:

[image: ImageLayout]

I want that big imageView, little shaded stripe with TextView and Like button. Any ideas how to solve this ? especially that shading part.

Comment: Edited for improved grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set an adapter to your ListFragment using  setListAdapter(adapter).

You can create your own adapter implementing BaseAdapter.

Then you override getView like this:

```
@Override  
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

 View v = convertView;  
 CompleteListViewHolder viewHolder;  
 if (convertView == null) 
 {  
     LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext  
                      .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
     v = li.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);  
  }

  ImageView image = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image);
  TextView text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text);
  ... add the like button etc

  return v;  }
```

listitem.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/someImage" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/likeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Like" />

</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

gradient.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    android:shape="rectangle" >

<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:endColor="#00000000"
    android:startColor="#FF000000"
    android:type="linear" />

<corners 
    android:radius="0dp"/>
```

Comment: Well, thanks for this code, going to try it tomorow.

Comment: Your design approach worked but  now I got a lot of memory issues